# C# How do I reference a GroupBox using a string?

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, groupbox

I want to reference a GroupBox name using a string.

My code currently works. I want to change this line of code:

```
Line1.buttonName.BackgroundImage = CircleColours[i];
```

Line1 is the GrouBox name.
I'd like to be able to change Line1 to a string. Like this:

```
string groupBoxName = "Line1";
groupBoxName.buttonName.BackgroundImage = CircleColours[i];
```

The code doesn't work when I do this though. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

What you're currently trying to do won't work because `groupBoxName` is just a string, and those properties don't exist on a string.

You need to search the collection of controls on the `Form`.

```
string groupBoxName = "Line1";
GroupBox groupBox = (GroupBox)Controls[groupBoxName];
groupBox.buttonName.BackgroundImage = CircleColours[i];
```

If it's buried within child controls, you'll want to use the `Find()` method instead:

```
string groupBoxName = "Line1";
GroupBox groupBox = (GroupBox)Controls.Find("groupBoxName", true)[0];
groupBox.buttonName.BackgroundImage = CircleColours[i];
```